# why my patch call on lead retriggeres Assignment rules

Tags: apex, rest-api, assignment-rules, lead-assignment

I thought assignment rules will be triggered only once on record creation .
But in case of Lead I have a marketo integration which makes a PATCH call to update existing record which is already assigned a owner based on assignment rules .
But after the patch call the assignment rule is again called and the owner gets changed on the basis of record change values .

Is there a way to avoid the calling of Assignment rules again .

Answer (score 0):

I'm also get confused why it happens on PATCH, but it relates to **Assignment Header** of your request. Here is what the documentation says:

> The Assignment Rule header is a request header applied when creating or updating Accounts, Cases, or Leads

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_autoassign.htm